# How can I show a specific record near the top in list view without screen flicker?

Tags: filemaker

I have a script (in FileMaker 14) that sets a variable, `$_record_number`, to `Get ( RecordNumber )` based on a specific criterion. Once it's been set, I want to bring that record to the top in list view. (It's possible that the criterion is never fulfilled and that `$_record_number` is empty.)

The portion of the script that does this looks like the following:

```
Go to Record/Request/Page [ Last ]
Refresh Window []
Go to Record/Request/Page [ No dialog ; Max ( $_record_number ; 1 ) ]
```

When the `Refresh Window` step isn't present, the script doesn't work correctly. Instead of bringing the record to the top of the list view, it brings it to the bottom.

Unfortunately, the `Refresh Window` step causes the window to flicker as the script redraws the layout.

Is there a way to duplicate the end results of the above steps without using `Refresh Window` and avoid the screen redraw?

Failed techniques I've tried:

- Using `Refresh Object` instead of `Refresh Window` targeting objects in both the header and body
- Using `Go to Related Record` with a relationship to the target record

Answer (score 1):

If you're using FileMaker 13 or higher, you can try the `Refresh Object` script step instead of `Refresh Window`. See http://www.filemaker.com/help/13/fmp/en/html/scripts_ref2.37.62.html for more details on that specific step.

I've sometimes had issues refreshing portals without `Refresh Window`, but if you just need the text on a label or button to update when the variable does, it should work fine.

Comment: Thanks, @CristosLC, but I'm afraid that didn't work. I tried naming three items on the layout, something in the header, the label in the body and the field in the body, using `Refresh Object` on each of them while the `Refresh Window` step was commented out. The record ended up at the bottom instead of the top.

Comment: hrm, do you have a demo file we could look at?

Another approach you can try is to create a self-join and use `Go to Related Record`. I'm not sure whether that's feasible in your specific situation (depending how you set it up, you might lose your found set), nor am I entirely certain it would resolve the screen flicker. 

@brian_schick or another more experienced dev might also have a better approach.

Comment: I don't think the issue is complicated enough to warrant a demo file. It's just a list view of records (not a portal). I've tried using `Go to Related Record`, but that also brings the desired record to the bottom, not the top. I'm starting to think I may simply have to deal with the screen flicker.

Comment: You may be reaching a point of diminishing returns on this question, but do you know how many records fit on the screen? For instance, if the screen fits 10 records on it, and you want record *n*, could you go to record *n + 10* -- which would show up at the bottom of the screen, and put the record you want at the top of the list view?

Comment: Interesting idea. It's an iPad app, so I can say for certain how many records are visible depending on the orientation of the device. I'll try it when I return to the project in a day or two.

Answer (score 0):

Chuck, one straightforward option would be to add an unstored calc field to your portal table, with a calc of Get(RecordNumber) = $_record_number. You could set the sort of your portal to reverse sort on this calc field. Since only the matching field should match, this should always pop the desired record (if any) to the top, and otherwise, this condition would be ignored.

Another option would be to manually step through your portal in a Loop and stop when you find a match.

Last, I'd wonder if it might be cleaner to store and test against your portal table's primary key instead of its record number, but that's of course beyond the scope of this question. Good luck :-)

Comment: this isn't a portal, but a list view, and I don't want the target record to be first in the list in the found set, I want it to be at the top of the window but retain its position in the found set. Simply looping doesn't work because that will place the desired record at the bottom, although you've given me the idea to try going to the record, performing a page down, go to prev, go to next.

Answer (score 0):

I am in FM14, and I think this works: get rid of your lines that go to last record and refresh window and instead insert 'Scroll Window [ End ]', e.g.

> `Scroll Window [ End ]`
>
> `Go to Record/Request/Page [ No dialog ; $recordNumber ]`